# how should utf8_general_ci data be stored?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, case-insensitive, diacritics

i'm using utf8_general_ci, how should data be stored?

i mean like if i have a varchar/text that contains special chars like **áéíóúàèìòùçÇÀÉÌÒ**, they are stored like that or they are converted in some way? im making a **CASE/ACCENT INSENSITIVE** search, but people told me i wasnt properply storing data, so i need a reference

so confused about this, even my ORDER BY is not working because the data is broken (after i know how data should be store im going to convert my database, the tables/setnames are already utf8_general_ci / utf8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i'm using utf8_general_ci, how should data be stored?

Just store it properly. :)

Seriously: You should store it so that, when you view the UTF-8 encoded database through an UTF-8 encoded connection in a program like phpMyAdmin or HeidiSQL, you see the actual characters `áéíóúàèìòùçÇÀÉÌÒ`. Nothing more to it.

`utf8_general_ci` is already accent insensitive in that

```
 á = a
 é = e
```

if you use a LIKE clause `columnname LIKE "searchterm"` instead of `columnname = "searchterm"`, it will also be case insensitive.

Comment: thanks! now i need to find whats wrong with my adodb connection, i already tried $db->execute("set names 'utf8'"); but its not working...so far i can only make it work when i prepare the query using utf8_decode

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the data is broken? When you retrieve it from the table, are all the accents missing? UTF-8 is a character set, utf8_general_ci is a collation. They're are different. If you want your ORDER BY to truly sort correctly, you may want to use utf8_unicode_ci instead. Collation is mainly in reference to searching and sorting, not storing.

Can you post your SHOW CREATE TABLE result?

Comment: yeah, my ó was stored as Ã³ ... and in phpmyadmin i was seeing all these weird chars everywhere.. im always using ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci...and everything like set names, i tried

Comment: If you run the query SET NAMES UTF8 on the database connection, that usually clears it. Although, you also need to make sure your web page is set to render in UTF8. If any of those are not set, your UTF8 character will show as 2 characters.